# How to spool to multiple files within a loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12c.

I have a table of EMPLOYEES that looks something like this:

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME | DEPARTMENT_NAME
--------------|----------------
Jim           | Sales
Barb          | Marketing
Paul          | Sales
Frank         | Sales
Cindy         | Accounting
Carl          | Marketing
... and so on ...
```

I would like to do something like this if PL/SQL permitted it:

```
FOREACH dept IN (SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM EMPOLYEES) DO
    SPOOL 'list_' || :dept || '.txt';
    SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME = :dept;
    SPOOL OFF;
DONE;
```

which would result in a set of files like this:

list_Sales.txt :

```
Jim
Paul
Frank
```

list_Marketing.txt

```
Barb
Carl
```

list_Accounting.txt

```
Cindy
```

... and so on ...

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Spool it to a single file. Use `awk`/ `sed` or equivalent to split it into multiple files

Comment: Alternately use UTL_FILE to write your output to files from PL/SQL.

Answer (score 5):

`spool` is a client command, it doesn't have any meaning within a PL/SQL block; and you can't write to files on the client machine from PL/SQL. You could write to the *server* using `utl_file` (as @kfinity suggested, and @BarbarosÖzhan demonstrated), but that might not be appropriate for your situation.

If you want to stick with spooling to the client machine, and don't want to post-process the output into multiple files (as @KaushikNayak suggested), you could use another level of spool to generate a script, something like:

```
spool temp_script.sql

select distinct 'spool list_' || department_name || '.txt' || chr(10)
  || 'select employee_name from employees where department_name = '''
    || department_name || ''' order by employee_name;' || chr(10)
from employees;

spool off

@temp_script.sql
```

As a more worked-through example using the default HR schema employee and department tables:

```
set pages 0
set lines 500
set trimspool on
set feedback off
set echo off

spool temp_script.sql

prompt set pages 0
prompt set lines 500
prompt set trimspool on
prompt set feedback off
prompt set echo off

select distinct 'spool list_' || department_name || '.txt' || chr(10)
  || 'select employee_name from employees where department_name = '''
    || department_name || ''' order by employee_name;' || chr(10)
from employees;

prompt spool off

spool off

@temp_script.sql
```

The contents of `temp_script.sql` in this case end up as something like:

```
set pages 0
set lines 500
set trimspool on
set feedback off
set echo off
spool list_Administration.txt
select first_name || ' ' || last_name from employees where department_id = 10 order by last_name, first_name;
spool list_Marketing.txt
select first_name || ' ' || last_name from employees where department_id = 20 order by last_name, first_name;
spool list_Purchasing.txt
select first_name || ' ' || last_name from employees where department_id = 30 order by last_name, first_name;
...
spool list_Payroll.txt
select first_name || ' ' || last_name from employees where department_id = 270 order by last_name, first_name;
spool off
```

and one file for each department, e.g. `list_Accounting.txt`:

```
William Gietz
Shelley Higgins
```

and `list_Executive.txt`:

```
Lex De Haan
Steven King
Neena Kochhar
```

etc. In this example there are several empty files, but if I'd made the initial query join the two tables there wouldn't have been; as you're querying a single table that won't happen for you either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
<kbd>[`utl_file`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS069)</kbd> 
package to generate operating system stream file as @kfinity pointed out

1) Create a directory in Oracle where you want file to be written. This directory/path has to be accessible and writeable from the database server.

```
CREATE DIRECTORY UTL_FILE_DIR AS '/scratch/data/file_data';
```

2)
Now get read write access to this directory.

```
grant READ, WRITE on UTL_FILE_DIR to <reporting_user>;
```

3)  Code that will generate the file.

```
declare
    v_outfile  utl_file.file_type;
    v_file     varchar2(100);
    v_path     varchar2(100) := 'UTL_FILE_DIR';
                           -- alias for the directory where your text files generated at OS.
begin
    for d in ( select distinct department_name as dept from employees )  
    loop  
        v_file    := 'list_'||d.dept||'.txt';
        v_outfile := utl_file.fopen(v_path, v_file, 'w');
      for c in ( select employee_name from employees where department_name = d.dept )
      loop
       begin 
         utl_file.put_line(v_outfile,c.employee_name);                 
       end; 
      end loop;
        utl_file.fclose(v_outfile); 
    end loop;
end;
```