SQLPlus dynamic spool filename from Table in a FOR Loop
I am very new to Oracle Develop PL/SQL language (so please excuse limited understanding). I am trying to use a spool command to dynamically create a filename based upon a table row values.
Below is the FruitCost table. And I want to create a CSV file for each of the rows. e.g.

10_apple.csv
11_orange.csv etc.




id
name
minprice
maxprice




10
apple
2.5
4.5


11
orange
1.0
2.5


12
banana
0.5
1.5



With some effort and much help from Stackoverflow, I have come up with the below script, but it is not working. I have tried to use substitute variable and assign bind variable to substitute variable.
begin
    for r in (select * from fruitCost)
    Loop
    var id number(6)
    var name varchar2(10)
    begin
        :id := r.id;
        :name := r.name;
    end;
    
    column test new_value s_id noprint 
    select :id test from dual;
    
    column test new_value s_name noprint 
    select :name test from dual;

    spool \&s_id || '_' || &name..csv
    
    /*  query */
    
    spool off;
    
    end loop;
end;

I am using SQL Developer v.22.2 on Windows 10. Please help.
Thank you.

Why do you want this?  You can't combine PL/SQL with SQL*Plus commands.  PL/SQL runs on the server, SQL*Plus is a client tool.  You could use the utl_file package in PL/SQL to generate a file but that would generate files on the server not on the client.

I would like to create csv files on the client machine using spool. In my limited online search, there was some workaround to do this, but as I said, I am kind of new at this, so any useful information is much appreciated. Thanks.

You're probably not going to be able to do this solely in a SQL*Plus script.  At least not without doing something hokey like writing a SQL*Plus script that queries the database and generates additional SQL*Plus scripts to do the actual spooling or "cheating" and calling a shell script from within SQL*Plus.  It would be far more sensible in 99.999% of cases to write a SQL*Plus script that took a couple of parameters and call that from a shell script that queried the database and passed the parameters to the SQL*Plus script.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576215/how-to-spool-to-multiple-files-within-a-loop

@JustinCave, can you please help with the shell script that can do as you recommended? Thank you.

You can use the below script for your requirement which will create a header and then spool the columns in csv format.Please note press F5 to run the script.
    set pages 0
    set lines 500
    set trimspool on
    set feedback off
    set echo off

    spool E:\temp_script.sql


    select  distinct  'spool E:\'||id||'_'||name||'.csv' || chr(10)
      || ' SET SQLFORMAT CSV'||chr(10)||' select * from fruitCost where id = '''
        || id ||''''|| ' and name='''||name ||''''||' order by id,name;' || chr(10)|| 'spool off'||chr(10)
    from fruitCOst;

    spool off

    @E:\temp_script.sql

